# Scoping of a variable inside a function in python?

Tags: python

I am new python & was trying to use the eval expression as shown below in my code , 
when i call the some_func()(Commented) I get **"NameError: name 'i' is not defined "**
but when i call the try_print func directly as shown below could able to print the value of i ,

What is the difference between calling the try_print directly & via function ?

How to achieve this using the some_func() ?

```
def try_print(string):
    print eval(string)

def some_func():
    global gameset
    gameset = "gamese,gamese1"
    for i in gameset.split(","):
            try_print('''"Trying to print the value of %s" %i''')

#some_func()
gameset1 = "gamese,gamese1"

for i in gameset1.split(","):
        try_print('''"here the value  is printed %s" %i''')
```

Comment: My god... Just a comment off-topic: Avoid `eval` in this case, pleeeease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `some_func`, `i` is a local variable. And a local variable can't be accessed outside of a function.

In the second case `i` is a global variable, so a function can access a global variable.

Just pass `i` to `some_func` if you want to do it that way:

```
def try_print(string, i):
    print eval(string)

def some_func():
    global gameset
    gameset = "gamese,gamese1"
    for i in gameset.split(","):
            try_print('''"Trying to print the value of %s" %i''', i)
```

But it's never a good idea to use `eval`, simply use string formatting:

```
print "Trying to print the value of %s" %i
```